# Is it normal to pass on context to lots of methods?

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton, android-context

I am using different objects (for example a large Bitmap) in many activities, which is why I created a class called `DataHolder` that holds a lot of those shared objects as static objects.

However, I also use shared preferences a lot, which is why that data class also holds a singleton of a shared preferences helper class called `Shop`.

This in combination with the shared bitmap etc. leads to me having to pass on a context to every single method that uses the `Shop`! I probably have a context object as an argument to 50% of my methods, which is quite annoying.

Is it normal to pass on contexts a lot?

How can I improve my data structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? I need to acces both classes from different activities without modifying different instances of the `Shop` of other data inside the `DataHolder`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might consider having a global `ApplicationContext` which can serve your purpose for loading the `DataHolder` object. Usually I do not use such contexts, however, your situation makes perfect sense of using a global application context in my opinion.

To achieve that, you might consider having the following class in your project.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static MyApplication myApplicationInstance;

    public static MyApplication getMyApplicationInstance() {
        return myApplicationInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myApplicationInstance = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return getMainApplicationInstance().getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

And add this `Application` class to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, under the `application` tag like the following.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Your activity declarations go here-->

</application>
```

Hence instead of passing the `Context` around, you might have a context supplied from a single space and hence improving your data structure. Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't use `getApplicationContext()` because I can't access that method in most of the relevant classes... Of course I use `this` as the context in activities etc, but in non-activity classes I rely on passed-on contexts

**EDIT**: I also can't store a `Context` in the `Shop`, because then I would be holding an object (singleton of `Shop`) which is holding a context as a static object, which is a memory leak. (The shop-singleton is stored statically in the `DataHolder`class)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code. Please check now. Yes, I forgot that you are using that from a Singleton class which is not an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. Hence you need to pass a context from your `Activity` first while initializing the `Shop`. Then you might consider using that everywhere else. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I see. Okay let me write another solution. :)

Comment: Well I did it that way before, but the problem is that I can only use this as long as the MainActivity is running, right?

Comment: Actually, as long as your application is running. Are you sure that you have done this before? This is not an `Activity` class. This is an `Application` class.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint, I didn't realize that. Do I put all the code I have in my MainActivity currently into the MainApplication, or do I call the MainActivity from the MainApplication?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192133/discussion-between-finni-and-reaz-murshed).

Comment: You do not have to call `MyApplication` from anywhere. Once you have added this under the `application` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, it's done. And yes, you do not have to copy everything from your `MainActivity` as well. I posted a working version of `MyApplication` class. Just use that I think.

Comment: Works like a charm except I have to use `getMainApplicationInstance().getApplicationContext();` instead of `getApplicationContext();` in `getAppContext()` because `getApplicationContext();` can't be called statically

Comment: Great to know that I could help. The answer is updated. :)